# How to add a program in safe mode start up registry using batch script?

Tags: batch, windows-registry, safe-mode

We have a custom student computer activity monitoring software. I need a batch script to add this program in **start up registry so no one can avoid by using safe mode**.

I want edit this registry
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell

The default Value is.... Shell= explorer.exe

I want to edit it like.... Shell= explorer.exe,MyApp.exe

Or any other way whatever works.

I tried several codes and asked this this question many times in forums, But never really got a straight solution. Please help me out.

Comment: What you could do is write a batch script to run at logoff/shutdown that writes to the RunOnce registry key to run your program but the key name must begin with an asterisk to force it to run even in safe mode. You need to rewrite the key at some point because RunOnce keys are deleted when they are run.

Answer (score -2):

The following are files that programs can autostart from on bootup:

1. c:\autoexec.bat
2. c:\config.sys
3. windir\wininit.ini - Usually used by setup programs to have a file run once and then get deleted.
4. windir\winstart.bat
5. windir\win.ini - [windows] "load"
6. windir\win.ini - [windows] "run"
7. windir\system.ini - [boot] "shell"
8. windir\system.ini - [boot] "scrnsave.exe"
9. windir\dosstart.bat - Used in Win95 or 98 when you select the "Restart in MS-DOS mode" in the shutdown menu.
10. windir\system\autoexec.nt.
11. windir\system\config.nt